# html not working in haml/ror form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am new to ror. How do I give required attribute for an input[not the required label that is provided by ruby]. When I write this,

```
= form.text_field :title, {html:{required: "required"}}
```

browser shows this,

```
 < input html="{:required=>&quot;required&quot;}" id="key_date_title" 
name="key_date[title]" size="30" type="text">
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [`text_field helper`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-text_field). It requires 3 arguments: object_name, method and options = {}. *You can pass in any standard HTML attributes directly in options argument.*

```
= form.text_field :title, required: true
```

Comment: I want <input required type="text">. Not the required provided by ror

Comment: @Vani Both of them are same, text_field helper will generate input of type text and required will validated that it's present.